# Trigger a popup at a specific time with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, time, popup

I want a javascript code, that triggers a popup on a specific time.

For example;

A) Lets say current time is; 01/01/2017 00:00:52
01/01/2017 00:00:00 -> 01/01/2017 00:00:52 => timeDifference 52 seconds.

B) I want to popup opened at "01/01/2017 00:04:00".
i get the value from querystring like "240" seconds. (In seconds)(Not in datetime)
 When the popup to be opened in seconds difference date from 01/01/2017 00:00:00
01/01/2017 00:00:00 -> 01/01/2017 00:04:00 => timeDifference 240 seconds.

So, when 52 reaches to 240, I want to trigger the popup.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)(function(){},querystring*1000)]

Comment: i cant use setTimeout, because while the page is loading, it probably takes 1-2 seconds, so with this it passes the specific time, based on a page load time

Comment: use this inside onload .